# Solenoid core and magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I understand the core of a solenoid can help increase magnetic field produced by a given current and every metal has a specified permeability $\mu$, but what if we had a hybrid core, say 50% iron ($\mu=200$) and 50% nickel ($\mu=100$)? If I want to find the total $\mu$ of the core, can I determine the $B$-field produced by a given current by multiplying each $\mu$ to the percentage and add up?

Comment: Are we talking an alloy or a lamination? In the former, I would say no, and in the latter, I would be inclined to say yes.

Comment: well, it's not an alloy, so i think he meant a lamination.
they are 2 half cylinders , one made of iron and one made of nickel , so no , this is not an alloy like mumetal